# how does fetch api interact with flask aplication

Tags: python, flask

I would like to understand better how flask path interact with JS code , specifically fetch api

```py
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    return render_template("apology.html") #test line of code
    try:
        with limiter.limit("1/10second"):
            if request.method == "POST":
                logging.info("msg sended")
                data = request.json
                user_id = session["user_id"]
                if not data:
                    logging.info("DATA IS MISSION")
                    return render_template("apology.html")
                if not session.get("user_id"):
                    logging.critical("This is a critical message")
                    logging.info("SESSION IS MISSSION")
                    return render_template("apology.html")
                db.execute("INSERT INTO user_messages_2 (user_id, user_message) VALUES (?,?)", user_id, data)
                return render_template("apology.html")
    except RateLimitExceeded:
        return "Too many requests, please try again later"
```

```js
async function frontend_msg(){
  const value_message = document.getElementById("chat_message").value
  const response = await fetch("/submit", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(value_message) //message or data in here   and make it a string
  });
  if (response.status != 200) {
            console.log('Error: Response status is not 200');
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 6000));
            // you can call the function again to retry sending the message
            frontend_msg();}

  //document.getElementById('bad_form_design').reset();
  document.getElementById('chat_message').value = ""
}
```

in this example I am sending "post" request to my flask app with the value of what user typed in inputform
and as you can see I added this line of code
`return render_template("apology.html") #test line of code`

and I was expecting this to happen when someone sends "post" request to my flask app

1. post request gets send to the "/submit" path
2. the page instantly renders  return render_template("apology.html") #test line of code
   instead the code below "return render_template("apology.html") #test line of code" just does not run which it makes sense I guess

context matters here and it looks like that "/submit" returns "render_template("apology.html")" to javascript and javascript  has no idea what "render_template("apology.html")" means so it just does nothing

so I was wondering am I correct in this theory or is something else happening , and how else can I change the page after someone types in that input field and sends json data to flask
}

Answer (score 0):

The Fetch-API is to be used if you want to send or load data without having to reload the entire page. Basically, the call initially does nothing other than send a request.
If a response from the server is expected and should be processed, this must be specified in the code. The browser does not do this by itself. Either a `then` block is used or the response was awaited and then something is done with the response.

In your example, however, the response data is ignored and therefore nothing is done.

If the template rendered and sent by the server is to be inserted into the page, the data must first be read from the stream. The data obtained can then be added to the page.
The following simple example shows you one possible use of the Fetch-API in conjunction with `render_template`.

###### ./app.py

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/data')
def index_data():
    return render_template('index_data.html')
```

###### ./templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-demo">Click Me</button>
    <output id="value"></output>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            const outValue = document.getElementById('value');
            const btnDemo = document.getElementById('btn-demo');
            btnDemo.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                const data = await fetch('/data', { method: 'post' })
                    .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text());
                if (data) {
                    outValue.innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### ./templates/index_data.html

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```